Files not showing up in a SMB share
This is a very strange one.
I mounted a smb share. Here the fstab entry:
//192.168.1.60/media /media/share cifs rw,noauto,username=myuser,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,nobrl,vers=3.11 0 0
I copy files/folders to it but some of them do not show up on the share.
They do exists on the filesystem if I directly connect to the source server.
I am on Debian 12 and Kernel 6.1.0-20.
Not sure if this is important: smbclient version 4.17.12-Debian
I poked a little bit around and found some strange behaviour:

ls file.txt does not show anything
mv file.txt anothername.txt works and anothername is showing up with ls
if I rename it back to file.txt it disappears again
when I have two files like file.mkv and file.nfo and only file.nfo visible I can rename file.nfo to something else and file.mkv is showing up
I also have this issue with whole folders

I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be welcome.
